# getopt_long() function with custom argc and argv

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments, getopt, c-libraries

I am having trouble using getopt_long() function with custom argc and argv.

I receive my arguments in a string instead of the real command line args. Then a new_argc and new_argv was built from this string to be used with getopt_long(). But getopt_long() fails on the first call itself. returns EOF and optarg = NULL.

```
string is "-c 10.30.99.41" 
new_argc = 3
new_argv[0]=>./prog_name
new_argv[1]=>-c
new_argv[2]=>10.30.99.41
```

getopt_long works OK for me if I pass command line args. So my short and long options are correct. But if I pass the new_argc and new_argv it fails.

I am sure my short and long options are right and the argv is NULL terminated. I apologize I cant post more code here.

I doubt if getopt_long can be used with a custom argc and argv. I suspect it works only with a real argc and argv because it must be referencing some other code in libc related to argc,argv. Any comments?

```
option = getopt_long( new_argc, new_argv, short_options, long_options, NULL );
```

Comment: Are you going to post what the string is and how it is being used to build the list?

Comment: @anoop, what about the `optstring` argument? Can you post the code that calls `getopt_long()`?

Comment: I've no idea if this will make a difference, but `new_argv[4]` should be 0 if you want to simulate how `main()` is really called.

Comment: thanks, argv is NULL terminated.

Comment: @anoop That would have been more obvious if you'd just showed the real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

"The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed in argv.  The system initializes this value to 1.  The caller can reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning a new argument vector."

So, yes. You can use getopt_long to scan the arguments or another argument list  again. However, if someone has called getopt_long previously, you have to set the global optind variable to back to 1.

Remember that the `argv` in  main() is NULL terminated and `argc` long, that is; argv[argc] == NULL. So you likely have to make sure the last element in your own `new_argv` is a NULL pointer.

(Note, please show all the relevant code when posting, it's hard to guess what the error is, e.g. showing what `short_options`, `long_option` is, how you actually build your new_argv, variable declarations etc.)

Comment: Hit the nail on the head man, thanks, much appreciated. optind = 0 or 1 fixes it. getopt_long was used earlier.